# Implement parcelable with kotlin on an existing java class

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am using [UsbSerialForAndroid](https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android) library for implementing a serial port connection to a device.

I need to send a `serial port` object across activities. The definition for the UsbSerialPort is [here](https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android/blob/master/usbSerialForAndroid/src/main/java/com/hoho/android/usbserial/driver/UsbSerialPort.java).

At the moment, my code is able to return a string specifying  port address with the help of `putExtra` method of `Intent`. I wish to send the `serial port` to the other activity (this is because I am not able to recreate the serial port object from address).

In order to send an object along with an `Intent` the object should be parcelable. But the original **library** class file is in java.

How to implement parcelable on such a pre-existing java class? I prefer to use kotlin language to achieve this.

## EDIT

One option that seems logical is to use the **original** `SerialUsbPort` class as a base class and extent the new class to parcelable (with @Parselize annotation) and then **cast the old object into new** (is that even right?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wish to send the serial port to the other activity (this is because I am not able to recreate the serial port object from address).

Unfortunately, to implement `Parcelable` you need to do exactly this: tell Android how to write some data to a `Parcel` and how to recreate this object from the data.

`@Parcelize` doesn't change this requirement, it just tells the compiler to generate these methods in a standard way.

To access a "live" object which you can't recreate, extend `Binder` instead (see https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services#Binder for an example in Java). Now you can store a `Binder` in a `Parcel` when implementing `Parcelable`.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the insight. I am looking at the link you shared, it seems to be talking about binders in the context of `services`, I do not see Binder extension there.

Comment: See `class LocalBinder`. In your case you just need to store `val port: UsbSerialPort` instead of the `getService` method.

Comment: Alternately, create a service through which you'll access the port (that would be my preference).

Comment: Just a bit of more info on implementing `Service`. Did you mean I should return a `UsbSerialPort` from the service? Or that the service will take care of I/O so I only communicate text to/from service, no `port` passing business.

Comment: If all activities (or fragments, services, etc) which need to access the port are in one process and a port can safely be used from multiple threads (probably not?), I'd go with the first option, otherwise with the second one.

Answer (score 2):

So, your problem, in summary, is that you need to send an instance of a library object; but to send it, it needs to implement an interface. Correct?

There are a few ways of doing this with Java/Kotlin interop, but none of them are particularly original. You're fortunate, actually, that the library you're using was not also written in Kotlin, because Kotlin classes are by default `final`. Java classes, on the other hand, are not; which is why you are able to do something like this:

`MySerialPort.kt`

```
class MySerialPort : UsbSerialPortImpl(), Parcelable {
  ...
}
```

This is, of course, assuming a few things:

1. That you're using a `UsbSerialPort` implementation from the library. The class you linked, after all, is an Interface, rather than a concrete class. You must be getting a concrete class from *somewhere* to be able to initialize it, so I'm assuming it's a library class.
2. That the `UsbSerialPortImpl` class is not `final`. As mentioned above, this (fortunately for you) isn't the default in Java, so you're probably good.